# Equivalence of Categories via Copower Functor

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, category-theory

If $C$ is a category with finite limits and coproducts, then there is a copower functor

$\coprod :\text {Set}\to C$ that sends sets $I$ to $\coprod_{i\in I} 1$ and on functions $f:I \to J,\ \coprod $ is defined in the obvious way using the UMP of the coproduct.

Now fix $I\in \text {Set}.$ The claim is then that $C/\coprod I\cong C^I$ is an equivalence of categories. I am filling in the details of the proof and am stuck on the last part. Here is what I have:

$1).$ Define $F:C^I\to C/\coprod I$ by $F(X_i)_i=p_x:\coprod_i X_i\to \coprod_i 1$ where $p_x$ is the unique arrow that satisfies $p_x\circ i_i=i'_i\circ !$ where $i_i$ and $i'_i$ are the injections: $X_i\to \coprod_i X_i$ and $1_i\to \coprod_i 1$, respectively. On arrows, $F$ is defined as usual through the UMP of the coproducts: if $(f_i)_i:X_i\to Y_i$ then $F(f_i)_i$ is the unique arrow: $\coprod_i X_i\to \coprod_i Y_i$ that satisfies $i^Y_i\circ f_i=F(f_i)_i\circ i^X_i$. It's easy to check that $F(f_i)_i$ is indeed a morphism in the comma category.

$2).$ Define $G: C/\coprod I\to  C^I$ to be the functor that sends $\phi: c\to \coprod I$ to $(c_i)_i$ where $(c_i)_i$ is defined though the pullback

\begin{array}{&&} 
c_i & \stackrel{h_i}{\to}& c\\ !
\downarrow & & \downarrow \phi \\ 
1 & \stackrel{i_i}{\to} & \coprod_i 1
\end{array}

On arrows $f:\phi \to \psi, \ Gf$ is the unique arrow $(\Phi_i)_i$ that satisfies $h'_i\circ \Phi_i=f\circ h_i$ and $!'\circ \Phi_i=!$ for each $i\in I.$

$3).$ It's straightforward to show that there is a natural isomorphism $\epsilon:FG\to 1.$

$4).$ For the other direction, we note that $GF(X_i)_i=(c_i)_i$ where the $(c_i)_i$ is defined through the pullback

\begin{array}{&&} 
c_i & \stackrel{h_i}{\to}& \coprod_i X_i\\ !
\downarrow & & \downarrow p_x \\ 
1 & \stackrel{i_i}{\to} & \coprod_i 1
\end{array}

If we set $c_i=X_i$ and $h_i=i'_i$ then the square commutes, and $if$ it is also a pullback, then I can show that this assignment induces a natural transformation $\eta:1\to GF$. How do I show that the square is a pullback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unable to prove that the square is a pullback square, because it does not hold in general. In fact, the equivalence you are trying to prove does not hold in general.

Suppose, for example, that $C$ is a non-trivial complete and cocomplete poset; the simplest example is $C = 2,$ the category with two objects and one non-identity arrow from one object to the other. Then $\coprod_{i \in I} 1 = 1,$ and the category $C/1$ is equivalent to $C$ itself. Obviously in general, $C^I$ is not equivalent to $C$. The functors you have defined are the coproduct functor $C^I \to C$ and the diagonal $C \to C^I$.

For the example $C = 2 = \{0 \to 1\}$, suppose that $I = \{a,b\}$, and let $X_a = 0$ and $X_b = 1$. Then the square you want to prove is a pullback is
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> 0 \lor 1\\
@VVV @VVV \\
1 @>>> 1 \lor 1
\end{CD}
$$
and this is obviously not a pullback.

Comment: Are there (minimal) conditions on CC that make this statement true? I need the result to see that certain fibrations can be reconstructed from others by change of base. There is a similar elementary result in Awodey's book and I thought it would extend to a more general case

Comment: I'm not quite sure. Perhaps you could take what you want to prove as a definition: namely, that the square you are talking about is a pullback. I'm pretty sure in most space-like categories it will be. You also might be interested in [disjoint coproducts](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/disjoint+coproduct), which *feel* like they ought to have something to do with this question, although I don't quite know yet what.

Comment: Yes, the missing assumption, at least, for my problem, seems to be that the coproducts be disjoint. In this case, the proof goes through. Thanks.